# Rails titlecase doesn't work on non-english letters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, utf-8

I'm trying to use titlecase to change an all uppercase words to nicer output.  It works with non english letters but not on other letters.  Is there any similar more UTF-8 friendly command?

```
"#{self.name.titlecase}"

Results:  SkjÖldÓlfsstaÐi
```

Johann

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work on unicode characters:

```
"SkjÖldÓlfsstaÐi".mb_chars.titlecase.to_s
```

Results: Skjöldólfsstaði